# Deploying Rails ActionCable using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, actioncable

I'm trying to deploy the chat demo from DHH on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've followed the tutorial here: https://keithpblog.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/rails-5-tutorial-chat-app-can-we-deploy-it And I've managed to get the solution deployed in a single instance and Redis up and running too. But when I try to post something, the message is saved in the db, but not returned by the WebSocket. I've checked the production.log and I can see this error message:

E, [2016-05-20T20:33:52.676577 #24281] ERROR -- : There was an exception - Gem::LoadError(Specified 'redis' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'redis'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by Action Cable).)

E, [2016-05-20T20:33:52.676826 #24281] ERROR -- : /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_cable/server/configuration.rb:37:in `rescue in pubsub_adapter'

/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_cable/server/configuration.rb:34:in `pubsub_adapter'

I also have in my Gemfile:
gem 'redis', '~>3.2'

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error by adding to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'em-hiredis'
gem 'redis'
```

The other change that I had to make was on /environments/production.rb

```
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://url.com/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://url.com']
```

And with that, I have actioncable up and running on Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: Hi did you have to do a external configuration on AWS?